# Search based on php url for keyword

Tags: php, search, web, web-crawler

Basically what I'm looking to do is search a url.

Example
http://www.example.com/?page=X

where X = 1 to 1500

Then find a keyword in the mess.

I thought of maybe using a sh script to do it but if anyone has another quick and dirty way that would be awesome.

Comment: "Then find a keyword in the mess. " what's that suppose to mean

Answer (score 0):

Question is vague, but if you just want to search for a single keyword, and then print something if found:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com/?page=$x";
$keyword = "keyword"; //The keyword you are looking for

/* Go from X=1 to X=1500 */
for($x=1; $x<=1500; $x++) {
    $current_page = file_get_contents($url); //This will parse the html into a single string
    if(strpos($current_page, $keyword) !== false) {
      echo "found keyword: $keyword on page $x \n";
    }
}
```

Docs:
http://php.net/strpos 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php